# The elliptic curve for $x_1^9+x_2^9+\dots+x_6^9 = y_1^9+y_2^9+\dots+y_6^9$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

**I.** *Theorem*: "If there are $a,b,c,d,e,f$ such that,

$$a+b+c = d+e+f\tag1$$

$$a^2+b^2+c^2 = d^2+e^2+f^2\tag2$$

$$3u^3-3uv+w=-def\qquad\tag3$$

with $(u,v,w)$ as the symmetric polynomials $u=a+b+c,\; v = ab+ac+bc,\;w = abc$, then,

$$(a + u)^k + (b + u)^k + (c + u)^k + (d - u)^k + (e - u)^k + (f - u)^k = \\ 
(a - u)^k + (b - u)^k + (c - u)^k + (d + u)^k + (e + u)^k + (f + u)^k\tag4$$

for $k=1,2,3,9$."

The first solution to $\sum\limits^6 x_i^9 = \sum\limits^6 y_i^9$ was found by Lander in 1967. In a [2010 paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2010-79-269/S0025-5718-09-02288-1/S0025-5718-09-02288-1.pdf), Bremner and Delorme realized that it had the form of $(4)$, was good for $k = 1,2,3,9$, was a rational point on a homogeneous *cubic* and thus one can find an *infinite* more. The first solution had $(a,b,c,d,e,f) = (9, 14, -19, 17, -18, 5).$

---

**II.** An alternative method  is to directly solve $(1),(2)$ with simple identities such as,

$$(a,b,c) = (3 + 3 m + n - 3 m n + x,\; -6 m - 2 n + x,\; -3 + 3 m + n + 3 m n + x)$$
$$(d,e,f) = (3 - 3 m + n + 3 m n + x,\quad 6 m - 2 n + x,\,\; -3 - 3 m + n - 3 m n + x)$$

which incidentally [also obeys](https://mathoverflow.net/q/222719/12905),

$$-a+nb+c = -d+ne+f$$

Then substitute it into $(3)$, and end up only with a *quadratic* in $m$ whose discriminant $D$ must be made a square. After some minor algebra, then one is to find rational $x$ such that,

$$y^2 = (-7x^3-21c_1x+c_2)(7c_1x+c_2)\tag5$$

where $c_1=(n^2+3)/8,$ and $c_2=(n^3-9n)/2.$ The situation is similar to the linked post for sixth powers.

**Question:** Is it possible to find an $x$ that is a non-trivial *polynomial solution* to $(5)$?

---

**P.S.** To clarify re comments, a polynomial solution would be $x,y$ as *rational functions* of $n$. Or $x,y,n$ as rational functions of a variable $v$.

Comment: I don't understand the question, but the upvotes suggest I may be dumb.

Comment: I don't understand the question either. Please clarify.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: A polynomial solution to $(1)$ is simply to express $x,y$ as polynomials $p_1(n), p_2(n)$ in terms of $n$. Or express $x,y,n$ as polynomials $p_1(m),p_2(m),p_3(m)$ in terms of some variable $m$. For example, the simplest is $x = -\frac{4(n^3-9n)}{7(n^2+3)}$ but this makes $y=0$.

Comment: Would solutions where $x$ and $y$ are rational functions in $n$ be admissible?

Comment: @JeremyRouse: Yes, did you find some?

Comment: I didn't find any other than the fairly silly $x = 0$, $y = \pm c_{1}$. I think it's quite likely that your elliptic surface has rank zero, given that it has many rank zero specializations.

Comment: @JeremyRouse: I think you mean $x = 0, y = \pm c_2$. I cobbled up some basic _Mathematica_ code and found that $$n =1/2,\, 1/8,\, 5/3,\, 5/4,\, 5/13,\, 7/9,\, 11/2,\, 11/16,\,17/9\,\dots$$ will do. Quite a lot, it seems

Comment: If I am understanding the link between the diophantine equation of the title and the family of curves $D$ correctly, then while there is an abundance of curves of zero rank, it might be of interest to look for a subfamily of $D$ of higher rank.

Comment: I think it is necessary to substitute $(1)$ in $(2),(3)$ . Then you need to reformulate the problem as the solution to this system of 2 equations. If you want to make it so, and then we will solve the system.

Comment: System $(1),(2)$ - has a simple solution.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/109106

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the equation,
\begin{equation*}
y^2=(-7x^3-21c_1x+c_2)(7c_1x+c_2)
\end{equation*}
where $c_1=(n^2+3)/8$ and $c_2=(n^3-9n)/2$, and assuming $n$ is rational, we have a rational point
$(0,c_2)$, so the quartic is birationally equivalent to an elliptic curve.

Using an ancient Ms-Dos version of Derive, it is easy to use Mordell's method to find the curve
\begin{equation*}
v^2=u^3+49((n^2+3)u+4(3n^6-5n^4+145n^2+49))^2
\end{equation*}
which has $2$ points of order $3$ at
\begin{equation*}
( \, \, 0 \, , \, \pm \, 28(3n^6-5n^4+145n^2+49)\, \, )
\end{equation*}
and numerical experimentation suggests that $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is the torsion subgroup.

The reverse transformation is
\begin{equation*}
x=\frac{8n(n^2-9)u}{(252n^6-420n^4+7n^2(u+1740)+3(7u+v+1372))}
\end{equation*}

Further numerical experimentation suggests that, for $1 \le n \le 19$, the curve has rank one for $n=6,7,8,9,12,15,16,17$, rank two
for $n=18$ and rank zero otherwise - the curve is singular for $n=3$.

The presence of rank $0$ curves means (I think!!) that there cannot be a polynomial solution in $n$, valid for all $n$. It might be possible
to find a parametric subset of n-values by investigating the curves with strictly positive rank. The problem is that the
curves do not have a point of order $2$, so finding generators can take time.

Allan MacLeod

Comment: After revisiting this question, I noticed that solutions to the system $$−a+12b+c=−d+12e+f$$ $$a^k +b^k +c^k =d^k +e^k +f^k$$ for $k=1,2,$  can be used for $6$th powers (like in [this post](http://mathoverflow.net/q/222719/12905)) as well as for $9$th powers discussed here.